# How to make Apache listen on a particular IP?

Tags: windows, apache-2.2

I have apache 2.2 installed on windows vista. Currently apache responds to http://localhost/ with its default "it works" page. My computer has multiple IPs on it and I want it to listen on a particular IP. How can I do this?

Comment: I'd dearly love to know why you've tagged this question "recapcha".

Answer (score 4):

Bind Apache's server port to `0.0.0.0` address.

In your Apache configuration use:

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
```

Or just:

```
Listen 80
```

Make sure you restart apache's daemon after changing this, and that your Windows Firewall is not preventing you from accessing port `80` through an external network interface.

Comment: Note that using 'Listen 0.0.0.0:80' or 'Listen 80' will cause Apache to listen and respond on all IP addresses your system is using.  If you want it to listen on a single IP, replace 0.0.0.0 with that IP.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to [run Apache and IIS on the same machine](http://iislogs.com/steveschofield/2007/07/07/iis7-post-44-iis7-and-apache-on-the-same-machine/), this is also possible.

Basically you have to tell the HTTP.SYS the IP addresses that you  want it to listened to. These are the IP addresses that you do not want to use with Apache.